# I'm trying to update my magic mirror using npm, using the following command in terminal: npm install -g npm

Tags: javascript

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm install -g npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/lib/node_modules/npm\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2019-01-13T02_13_34_227Z-debug.log
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo npm install -g npm`

Sudo is the key here. May the force be with you.

Comment: @DanukaYomal Accept the answer please.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow here

Comment: this is my first time using this forum  , actually i don't know how solved the problem. now i click the right sign and its appeared  green color. it's mean ok or not

Comment: This is totally fine. Welcome to StackOverflow.